# Elasticsearch query hits missing documents by search after

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a little problem when querying elasticsearch 6.8. I have a createdAt information in the documents and I am using createdAt information with search after

My query is:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 2500,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "uni",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "uni": {
                    "query": "false",
                    "operator": "OR",
                    "prefix_length": 0,
                    "max_expansions": 50,
                    "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                    "lenient": false,
                    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                    "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "pt",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "del",
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "del": {
              "query": false,
              "operator": "OR",
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "lenient": false,
              "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "minimum_should_match": "1",
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "did",
      "ca"
    ],
    "excludes": []
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "ca": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "search_after": [
    1596545647769
  ]
}
```

I have an 100k documents but with that way I am hiting 99.996 documents, the problem is totalHits shows the 100.000 but when I query on the kibana it gives me last batch as 4 missing documents. For example I am getting my documents as 2500 documents batches, in the last one it should be from 97.500 to 100.000 but it gives me 99.996.

When I do same query with search scroll api with 2500 documents batches, it gives me 100.000 documents.

Note: If I use search scroll, I am using scroll key to be able to continue. If I use search after, I am using createdAt information to get next documents.
What can cause this problem ?

Comment: Are there any documents that might contain the exact same value for the `ca` field? if yes, the solution is simply to use another tie break field in the sort clause so that two documents with the same `ca` can still be sorted properly.

Comment: Yes you are right. I hit the completed documents with using tieBreakerId + createdAt. Thank you very much. I can accept as an answer if you are able to add comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are any documents that might contain the exact same value for the `ca` field, then the solution would be to simply use another tie breaker field in the `sort` clause so that two documents with the same `ca`value can still be sorted properly.

Like this:

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "ca": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "tie_breaker_field": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
```